# Log, find the following values in term of m and n

Tags: logarithms, education

I have a hard time on this log question, can you explain it?

Given `log(x)p = m` and `log(x)q = n` find the following values in termm of m and n:

1)  `log(x)p^3q`

2) `log(x)P/q^2`

the base are (x)

For the first one my attempt are

`(log(x)m^3 )( log(x)n)`
`=` `nm^3`

the second one i have no idea how to do it

thanks guys

Comment: By log(x)p do you mean "log base x of p"?

Comment: And could you please use brackets to specify what you mean by "log(x)P/q^2".

Comment: In general $\log_x(ab)=\log_x (a)+\log_x (b)$. (The log of a **product** is the **sum** of the logs.) So $\log_x(p^3q)=\log_x(p^3)+\log_x(q)$. Also, $\log_x(a^b)=b\log_x(a)$. So $\log_x(p^3)=3\log_x(p)$. Putting things together, we get $3m+n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by log(x)p you mean ${\log_x}{p}$ and that by log(x)P/q^2 you mean ${\log_x}{p/q^2}$ then you would proceed as follows...

1) ${\log_x}{p^{3}{q}} = 3\log_x{p} + \log_xq = 3m + n$

2) $\log_x{p/{q^2}} = \log_x{p} - 2\log_x{q} = m - 2n$

Note that to simplify I used the rules...

1) $\log(ab) = \log{a}+\log{b}$ and

2) $\log{a^c} = c\log{a}$

Comment: oh myy thank you :) i got it now :D, i forgot the way but now its clear! thanks again! you are awesome

Comment: Edited a couple times. I hope this doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: no problem :) crystal clear now